# How I can use react-toastify promise while posting date using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-toastify

// Want to show spinner while posting and then success/error message using react-toastify
Is it possible?

```
axios.post("/orders.json", order)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.status);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: The documentation of React-Toastify is very comprehensive and helpful. Make sure to have a look at it. It covers almost all the use cases with implemented examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const promise=axios.post("/orders.json", order)

const res = await toast.promise(promise, {
        pending: "Posting",
        success: "Posted",
        error: "error message",
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can have a state called `isLoading` and you can set it to `true` when you submit a `post` request and you can check for `isLoading` before rendering your component like below.

```
 if(isLoading) {
     return (<Spinner />)
 }
```

And you can use toast to show `success/error` message after `post` method is executed.
Like below

```
 toast.error('Sorry request failed')
```

or

```
 toast.success('Request successfull')
```

But before use toast you have wrap your `App` component in `toast container` like below.

```
 import React from 'react';

 import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
 import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

 function App(){
    const notify = () => toast("Wow so easy!");

    return (
       <div>
          <button onClick={notify}>Notify!</button>
          <ToastContainer />
       </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your question.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
toast.configure({
    position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT
});

export default function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        loading: true,
        dataArray: []
    });

    const myRequest = async () => {
        try {
            const request = await axios.get(`/generic_data/search_skills`);
            const { error, msg, data } = request.data;
            if (error) throw new Error(msg);
            setState({ ...state, loading: false, dataArray: data });
            toast.success("All good, we have the data");
        } catch (e) {
            toast.error("Upps, someting went wrong");
        }
  };
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    myRequest()
  },[])

    if (state.loading) {
        return "Loading data from server.. this will take long time...";
    }

    return <div>The request has ended. We have the data</div>;
}
```